# How to update windows registry each 2 minutes?

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I am writing a scrip in VBA which will monitor the registry value and if it changes the script will overwrite it. Till now I wrote an script which checks the value in the registry and updates it to given value. But my problem is how to update the registry each 2 minutes or when the value changes ? Please help !!!

```
On Error Resume Next
HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Control Panel\Desktop"
ValueName = "ScreenSaveActive"
    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValue
    objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath
If IsNull(strValue) Then
    Wscript.Echo "The value is either Null or could not be found in the registry."
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Value: ", strValue
    strValue = "1"
    objReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValue
    Wscript.Echo "Value after change ", strValue
End If
```

Regards,
Erni

Comment: did you mean VBA or VbScript? Now you have two answers, one for each script language. :-)

Comment: Imagine if two programs did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code inside a loop and tell it to sleep for 2 minutes between each time through the loop, so something like this would probably work:

```
Do While 1

    ...
    [your code here]
    ...

    WScript.Sleep(120 * 1000) ' 120 seconds in 2 minutes and it expects milliseconds
Loop
```

But if the value is null, then there probably isn't any point in carrying on, so it might be worth adding a `Exit Do` line after the `Echo` about it being null to stop the loop if that's the case.

Please note though, you're using VBscript, not VBA (they are similar, but still different languages).

Comment: But with this approach you cannot do anything but the loop. Look at my example - there the timer code runs asynchronously in the background and you can do other things in parallel.

Comment: @Matt: True, but as I said in my answer, I think he had mistaken VBA for VBScript, since his code included `Wscript.Echo` and similar. Looking at the code I also think that this is probably some kind of quick and dirty hack solution, so making it "proper" is probably not a priority (otherwise I'd suggest a C++ Windows Service would be a good option).

Comment: Indeed, I would argue that code that overwrites a registry setting every two seconds is *by definition* a quick and dirty hack. :-)

Comment: ho1, Harry: I agree to what you've said. Ernie: Maybe its worth trying it in VisualStudio or Sharpdevelop (free) - with vb.net or c# there is much more possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following example is done in Excel VBA. Put the following code in `ThisWorkbook`:

> ```
> Option Explicit
> ```

```
Public TimerActive As Boolean
Public TimerInterval As String ' e.g. "00:02:00"
Public TimerProcedure As String
Private NextSchedule As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    TimerActive = False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextSchedule, _
                       Procedure:=TimerProcedure, Schedule:=False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TimerProcedure = "Module1.myTimerProc"
    TimerInterval = "00:00:10"
    TimerActive = True
    ScheduleTimer TimerInterval, TimerProcedure
End Sub


Public Sub ScheduleTimer(nextInterval As String, procName As String)
    NextSchedule = Now + TimeValue(nextInterval)
    Application.OnTime NextSchedule, procName
End Sub
```

Then, create Module1 as with the following procedure in it:

> ```
> Option Explicit
> ```

```
Public Sub myTimerProc()
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .TimerActive Then
            Debug.Print Now & " Hi!"
            .ScheduleTimer .TimerInterval, .TimerProcedure
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This prints in the debug (immediate) window every 10 seconds the message "Hi!". You can easily modify the example to write into the registry - just create another procedure in this module and replace the `Debug.Print` statement by a call of the procedure you've written. The timer is activated right after you've opened the excel file and deactivated before you close it.

**Note** that

- you need the `TimerActive` flag in the `Workbook_Close` event along with the `if` statement in `myTimerProc` to allow Excel to properly close: If you don't have this extra code it will re-fire the timer indefinitely.
- the file needs to be saved as "macro enabled workbook" and probably needs to be signed or put into a trusted location. Otherwise, the macros in it will not run (disabled by Excel).